# IntelliJ IDEA Vim Like editing

Tags: intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ 14 on Mac and I am getting an annoying issue with the text editor. It seems to be controlling in a similar way to vim. Every time I open a new file I need to press "i" on the keyboard in order to start inserting text. I would like to change it to a standard text edit mode like you would find in eclipse or any other visual text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you installed the IdeaVIM plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. You can uninstall it through Settings | Plugins if you don't want to use VIM modal editing inside IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: May be you pressed `Ctrl + Alt + V`. That enables the [ideavim plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) with the default keymap, if it is installed of cause.